# Herencia entre jpanel(problema de devolver datos)

Tags: java

Estoy intentando heredar del jpanel2 extends JPanel hacia el jpanel extends JPanel. pero a la hora de heredar y hacer todo, me reconoce la variable y todo, pero al dar click, no me devuelve nada mas lo que tengo impreso directamente desde el Actionperformed.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
package herenciaclases;

public class Frame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Jframe invocar=new Jframe();    
    invocar.setVisible(true);
    invocar.setTitle("herencia");
    invocar.setBounds(300,400,500,600);
    invocar.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    invocar.setLocationRelativeTo(null);    

}
} package herenciaclases;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Jframe extends JFrame {

public Jframe() {
    jpanel panel=new jpanel();

    add(panel);

    panel2 paneli=new panel2();
    add(paneli,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}
}

package herenciaclases;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton; import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class jpanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public jpanel() {

     aceptar=new JButton("aceptar");
     aceptar.addActionListener(this);
    add(aceptar);

}

public JButton aceptar=new JButton();
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    panel2 panelito=new panel2();
    String carga=panelito.texto.getText();
    System.out.print(carga);
    System.out.print("hola");

    panelito.carlos();    

}
}

package herenciaclases;

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JPanel; import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class panel2 extends JPanel {

public panel2() {


     texto=new JTextField("",15);
    add(texto);


}

JTextField texto=new JTextField();

public String carlos() {
    return "saltos";
}

}
```

Comment: No dupliques tus preguntas, edita la que tienes siguiendo los consejos que te dieron. Crear una pregunta exactamente igual a la anterior no van a aumentar tus chances de obtener una respuesta, mientras una pregunta de buena calidad si :)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Herencia entre JPanel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169548/herencia-entre-jpanel)

Comment: Me puedes ayudar? :v